# Would anyone please explain this transformation in the loss function to me?

Tags: transformation, error-function, mean-square-error

I have a foggy brain right now, I forgot how this happened. Would anyone please explain this to me? This is a loss function. The red circled part is the part I don't understand. How did it become the one after it?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** $$\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \;\; .$$

Comment: perfect answer! Thank you